# Android BLE auto disconnection issue

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

My android ble source works good on other devices but on galaxy note2, it keeps on disconnecting right after connection completion(service discovered).

There is no action between the connection and the disconnection.

Why is this happening?

Comment: It's hard to say without more data. Do you have a sniffer of any kind ? You can find a sniffer for ~50$ at Nordic (there's an Adafruit version that can be used with Wireshark)

Comment: Or just check the Bluetooth hci snoop log if there's something interesting there.

Comment: You can try adding some delay before initiating ServiceDiscovery, I don't know the rationale behind this logic but read somewhere it had some effect.

Comment: Connection complete doesn't mean service discovered.
Once you have connected, onConnectionStateChange on BluetoothGattCallback should be raised with state STATE_CONNECTED. From that point, you can initiate discoverServices on the gatt object.

When you exclude the discoverServices on the note 2, does the connection persist?

Comment: Eventually, I posted this question a long time ago, and yes, it was about the service discovery which was causing the issue. My only option was to write a retry logic which keeps trying to connect and discover, with the device nearby which has the most powerful rssi value.